# Problem is there in symbol table when building gdb binary for version 13.1 and 13.2

Tags: gdb, msys2, symbol-table

Actually I have built gdb.exe for 13.1 using "../configure --enable-debug" and then "make" command on msys on window. But when I check for symbol table using objdump -t path\to\gdb.exe , it is printing no symbols in symbol table. But when built using same commands on linux machine it is showing the symbol table. Can anyone please help me out in this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1ito.jpg)

Comment: Do you have an _actual_ problem? Windows and UNIX treat symbol table differently, and lack of symbol table on Windows doesn't necessarily indicate that there is any problem.